# Per vertex weighted normal keeping in mind the crease angle in OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, normals

I am trying to calculate the per vertex weighted normals, taking crease angle into account.
However, the code is taking forever to run as I have many (>12) mesh objects in my game.
Is tere any better way to calculate the per vertex weighted normals, keeping crease angle in mind?

Below is the piece of code showing it:

```
if (cosCreaseAngle == 0) { // ignore crease angle, just average all the nermoals keeping area in mind
    float area = 0;
    for (long pos = 0; pos < m->face_index_vertex.size(); pos++) {
        int firstVertex = pos - pos % 3;
        area = calcTriangleArea(m->dot_vertex[m->face_index_vertex[firstVertex]], m->dot_vertex[m->face_index_vertex[firstVertex + 1]], m->dot_vertex[m->face_index_vertex[firstVertex + 2]]);
        m->dot_normalPerVertexWeighted[m->face_index_vertex[pos]] +=
            area*(m->dot_normalPerFace[m->face_index_normalPerFace[pos]]); // multiply by the area
    }
}
else { //average the normals only when the angle between normals is less than the crease angle
    float area = 0;
    for (long pos = 0; pos < m->face_index_vertex.size(); pos++) {
        m->dot_normalPerVertexWeighted[m->face_index_vertex[pos]] = m->dot_normalPerFace[m->face_index_normalPerFace[pos]];
        for (long adjacentFace = pos + 3; adjacentFace < m->face_index_vertex.size(); adjacentFace++) {
            if (m->face_index_vertex[pos] == m->face_index_vertex[adjacentFace]) {
                if (cosCreaseAngle < calcAngleBetweenNormals(m->dot_normalPerFace[m->face_index_normalPerFace[pos]], m->dot_normalPerFace[m->face_index_normalPerFace[adjacentFace]])) {
                    int firstVertex = adjacentFace - adjacentFace % 3;
                    area = calcTriangleArea(m->dot_vertex[m->face_index_vertex[firstVertex]], m->dot_vertex[m->face_index_vertex[firstVertex + 1]], m->dot_vertex[m->face_index_vertex[firstVertex + 2]]);
                    m->dot_normalPerVertexWeighted[m->face_index_vertex[pos]] +=
                        area*(m->dot_normalPerFace[m->face_index_normalPerFace[adjacentFace]]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a nested loop that results in quadratic running time. You should instead build an adjacency graph -- for each vertex add the adjacent faces to a list, and then go over that graph. This will cut the running time to linear.